# Outside function not calling in lambda node js exports.handler?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

In lambda when we write node js script, is it possible to run a function outside of `exports.handler`?

For example:

```
// index.js

const main = async () => {

console.log(" running ");
};
main();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
 const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('done!'),
  };
return response;
};
```

If I need to run index.js in lambda, it is executing only inside function of `exports.handler`.
Its not executing the "main" function which is outside of `exports.handler`. please help someone

Comment: If you want to call `main()` function, you can call it from exports.handler function. What you are trying to achieve may help to give a better answer.

Comment: actually, in the main function i am having logic to connect mongo db...when main function  trying to connect, in handler also function running. and its failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comment it sounds like you are looking for a way to run a function to connect to MongoDB, but not rerun the connection every time the lambda function is called.

One method to resolve this is to cache the database connection in a variable in the outer scope.

```js
// Store db after first connection
let cachedDb = null;
// database connection function
const main = async () => {
  // Guard clause to return cache
  if (cachedDb) return cachedDb;
  
  // Only creates the connection on the first function call
  const client = await MongoClient.connect('your connection URI')
  const db = await client.db('your database')
  cachedDb = db;
  
  return db;
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const db = await main();
  // Add database interactions/queries
  // ...

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('done!'),
  };
return response;
};
```

Comment: I use same example in python but gives local variable assigned before assignment. for cachedDb